# Can't SELECT records from two tables properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been using this [Query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/weourGGnXWj2b6xu7mNfAp/10) at first, Then used this [Query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/weourGGnXWj2b6xu7mNfAp/12) at last
Which are

```
##Query[1]
SELECT t.title, p.content, p.version
FROM drafts d
INNER JOIN titles t ON t.id = d.tp_id AND d.t = 1
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.id = d.tp_id AND d.t = 2
WHERE user_id = 1

##Query[2]
SELECT coalesce(p.title, t.title), p.content, p.version
FROM drafts d
INNER JOIN titles t ON t.id = d.tp_id AND d.t = 1
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT pt.id, tp.title, pt.content, pt.version 
  FROM posts pt
  INNER JOIN titles tp ON tp.id = pt.tid
) p ON p.id = d.tp_id AND d.t = 2 
WHERE user_id = 1
```

What I want to do Using the `Table: drafts` to use

1. `Column: tp_id` as an identifier to the `Column: id` in other **tables**.
2. `Column: user_id` as the `id` of the **user** having the **draft**.
3. `Column: t` as the identifier to which table of `Tables: titles[t=1], posts[t=2]` to fetch the records from it.

In `Table: posts` the `Column: tid` links to the `Column: id` of `Table: titles` Which is used to pull the `Column: title`.

I want no records to be shown from the `Table: titles` if doesn't exist, And no records to be shown from the `Table: posts` if the title related using `tid` on `Table: titles` doesn't exist Or the record of the `Table: posts` doesn't exist, That why I used `INNER JOIN`.

But in both queries I don't get any results at all.

Is this even the proper **[table scheme and design](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/weourGGnXWj2b6xu7mNfAp/11)** to be used for something like the *Drafts table for two different tables instead of one for each table*?

The result I expect is something like this

```
title       content     version
TheTitle    null        null
TheTitle    Content1    1
TheTitle    Content2    2
TheTitle    Content3    3
TheTitle    Content4    4
TitleThe    Content1    1
TitleThe    Content2    2
TitleThe    Content3    3
TitleThe    Content4    4
```

---

A simple Example:

```
    [table-a]                                        [table-b]
[id   -   title  ]                          [id   -   table_a_id   -   content  ]
[1    -   title-1]                          [1    -   1            -   content-1]
```

1. `table-a` has the `titles`.
2. `table-b` has the `content` of each
   `title`.
3. `table-b` column of `table_a_id` links the `content` with
   the title of `table-a`.

---

```
                                    [table-ab]
                    [user_id   -   table_col_id   -   table_letter]
                    [1         -   1              -   a           ]
                    [1         -   1              -   b           ]
```

1. `table-ab` has `user_id` to tell which user will be shown the records.
2. `table-ab` has `table_letter` to tell the query which table to fetch the data from it.

---

What I want the Query to do is to check `table-ab` and fetch the data from the other tables according to it, so it would be

1. `table_letter = a` => fetching rows from `table-a`.
2. `table_col_id = 1` => fetching rows from `table-a` **WHERE** `id = 1`.

**`result = title-1`**

---

1. `table_letter = b` => fetching rows from `table-b`.
2. `table_col_id = 1` => fetching rows from `table-b` **WHERE** `id = 1`.

**`result = title-1 - content-1`**

---

```
Final result:
id -  title    -  content
-------------------------
1  -  title-1  -  null
2  -  title-1  -  content-1
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the schemas of the tables. No images please, just paste and format as code.

Comment: @SloanThrasher is this fiddle better to display it? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/weourGGnXWj2b6xu7mNfAp/7

Comment: `AND d.t = 1` ... `AND d.t = 2` dt cannot have two values at the same time. (Note: you are not selecting anything from  the `drafts` table)

Comment: It's best to paste the code in question to your question, but for now the SQL fiddle above works. Your query seems a bit over-complicated for the requirements you state.

Comment: @SloanThrasher couldn't think about a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @wildplasser In this case How can I get over this problem? I thought about making two subqueries, but i don't think it is the efficient solution.

Comment: In the last line of your question you ask if this is the best design for **this**. but you don't really describe what **this** is. IOW, the overall purpose for the datastore.

Comment: @SloanThrasher added what I meant by **this** now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two separate queries (for t=1 and t=2) and use `UNION ALL` to combine the results:

```
SELECT t.title, null content , null version
FROM drafts d
INNER JOIN titles t
ON t.id = d.tp_id 
WHERE d.user_id = 1 and d.t = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT pt.title, pt.content, pt.version
FROM drafts d
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT p.id, t.title, p.content, p.version 
  FROM posts p
  INNER JOIN titles t ON t.id = p.tid ) pt
ON pt.id = d.tp_id AND d.t = 2
WHERE d.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a big performance draw and it would be better if I used two separated queries in this case?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow.  Sounds like you have two mutually exclusive join requirements: t =1 use title; t=2 use price/title.  May be I am not understanding your requirement.

Comment: yes, that correct, you're query solves it too, But I was wondering if using `UNION` is efficient for it, Or if my table design actually is unefficient overall for any query.

Comment: The design does seem a bit unusual.

Comment: I can only think about two different tables of drafts for each table, but will use `UNION ALL` too, And would still give the same results, Do you have any recommendations I may use?

Comment: Should tp_id be split into 2 data fields: t_id and p_id?  That way you can put fk constraints to ensure they exist in the corresponding table if they are not null.  I don't know anything about your bz requirement. Should not recommend changes.  May be you post a design question for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **inner join** so please check the following:

1. Common data in both tables(joining column), if there will not be any common value it will not pick any thing.
2. Check data type of the column which are used to join both table that should be same if not then handle it
3. Extra spaces in the joining column.

Comment: it is the `tp_id` from the table `drafts` that has a common value, If the `t=1` it gets the `id = tp_id` from table `titles`, If it is `t=2` it gets the `id = tp_id` from table `posts`, the Table `posts` is linked with both the `drafts` by `id` and the `titles` by `tid`

Comment: It does not work like this,
(t=1 & id = tp_id) , (t=2 & id = tp_id) -> these are your condition which should be satisfied to fetch data from data base. please add some sample data also.

Comment: added a sample of the result i expect If that what you meant by sample data.

Answer (score 0):

After joining with condition `d.t = 1` there is no data for `d.t = 2` That's why after 2nd Join you are not getting any data. Try the below Query

```
SELECT coalesce(p.title, t.title), p.content, p.version
FROM drafts d
INNER JOIN titles t 
ON t.id = d.tp_id 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT pt.id, tp.title, pt.content, pt.version 
  FROM posts pt
  INNER JOIN titles tp 
  ON tp.id = pt.tid
) p 
ON p.id = d.tp_id 
WHERE user_id = 1
AND (d.t = 1 OR d.t = 2)
```

Comment: It only pulled *3* records from `drafts` for the `user_id = 1`, But he has *9* records in it.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tNo4SKrLFV2qTJdpRhpe9M/0

Comment: check `drafts d
INNER JOIN titles t 
ON t.id = d.tp_id`  condition for above condition you have only 3 records

Comment: `ON t.id = d.t ` use this in place of `t.id = d.tp_id`

Comment: doesn't that relate the `id` from the table `titles` with the column `t` of the table `drafts`?

Comment: can you explain me your Expected Output??

Comment: added a simple example explaining it now.

Comment: Check you sample data properly I think you did some mistake in sample data

Comment: yes, forgot to add the `table_col_id` added it now.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce almost exactly what you have in your question. It does omit the line with the null values for the content and version. Not sure why that would have been in the expected output.

```
SELECT 
    if(d.t = 1,tp.title, if(d.t = 2,t.title,"")) as `title`,
    p.content,
    p.version
FROM drafts d
LEFT JOIN titles t ON t.id = d.tp_id AND d.t = 2
LEFT JOIN posts p ON t.id = p.tid
LEFT JOIN titles tp ON tp.id = p.tid AND d.t = 1
WHERE user_id = 1 AND NOT p.content IS NULL
```

I changed some of the data, specifically the groups of Content1 - Content4. I added "a" to the first 4, and "b" to the remainder.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/weourGGnXWj2b6xu7mNfAp/5) that shows what it does.

Comment: The first row that has `null` values has the `t=1` which means it came from `Table: titles`, But this table doesn't have `content` or  `version` columns, I'll make a simple example of how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Did you take a look at the SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Yes, It removed the first row as you said but got the other values correctly, But it is the same as If i just left joined the `posts` alone without `titles` table. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/weourGGnXWj2b6xu7mNfAp/13 I'm adding a simple example to explain my tables now.

Comment: added the simple example now.